# how to get lastSibling by javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

There is a native "nextSibling" attribute,but how to get "lastSibling"?

Answer (score 5):

[**A Few functions to handle DOM events**](http://snipplr.com/view/1994/javascript-dom/)

from the article

```
function lastSibling(node){
    var tempObj=node.parentNode.lastChild; 
    while(tempObj.nodeType!=1 && tempObj.previousSibling!=null){  
    tempObj=tempObj.previousSibling;   
    }  
    return (tempObj.nodeType==1)?tempObj:false; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe:

```
Node.parentNode.lastChild
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question doesn't have any concerns related to that. Also, since author expressed awareness of nextSibling property, I thought he was aware of implications regarding document traversal and presence of different kinds of nodes in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the querySelector for that:

```
   function lastSibling(node) {
       return node === node.parentNode.querySelector(node.nodeName + ':last-of-type');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct method to access the last sibling; you simply need to iterate over all of the siblings until you reach the last one.

Answer (score 1):

```
node.children[node.children.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work same way as nextElementSibling, but the opposite direction

```
console.log(node.previousElementSibling.className);
```